# Tener un directorio(tomcat) compartido entre varios usuarios con permisos rwx en Centos 7

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos, permisos

Tengo un directorio "tomcat7" el cual necesito que varios user pueden iniciar/detener el servicio Y leer/escribir dentro del directorio "tomcat7"

Lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

- CREAR UN GRUPO

`groupadd PRUEBA`

- CREAR 2 USER DE PRUEBA

```
adduser user1

adduser user2
```

- AÑADIR ESTOS USER AL GRUPO "PRUEBA"

```
usermod -G PRUEBA user1

usermod -G PRUEBA user2
```

- CAMBIE EL PROPIETARIO DE "TOMCAT7" AHORA PERTENECE A USER "ROOT" Y GRUPO "PRUEBA"

`chown -R root:PRUEBA tomcat7/`

- LE DI PERMISOS RWX ESTO PERMITE QUE EL GRUPO LEA, ESCRIBA Y EJECUTE

```
find tomcat7/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; ---> directorios

find tomcat7/ -type f -exec chmod 775 {} \; ---> files
```

QUEDA ASÍ:

`drwxrwxr-x.  9 root PRUEBA      275 Apr 11 15:13 tomcat7`

- AHORA TODOS LOS ARCHIVOS/CARPETAS NUEVOS CREADOS EN "TOMCAT" A PARTIR DE AHORA HEREDEN EL NOMBRE DEL GRUPO

`chmod g+s tomcat7/`

QUEDA ASÍ:

`drwxrwsr-x.  9 root PRUEBA      275 Apr 11 15:13 tomcat7`

**EL PROBLEMA ES EL SIGUIENTE:**

Cuando Inicio el tomcat con el user "user1" el pid lo genera así

`-rw-rw-r--.  1 user1 PRUEBA       6 Apr 11 17:18 tomcat1.pid`

Cuando quiero bajar el servicio con el "user2" me dice que no tengo permisos

> PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current
>   user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***POR FAVOR SU AYUDA!!!***

Comment: ¿Te ha valido la respuesta? ¿Te puedo ayudar en algo más?

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a realizar una configuración de `sudoers`?

Un ejemplo:

Creamos el archivo `/etc/sudoers.d/10-tomcat-user1`

Ponemos dentro:

```
user1 ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart tomact7
user1 ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start tomact7
user1 ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop tomact7
```

Y ahora ese usuario podría hacer:

```
sudo systemctl restart tomcat7
```

Como root sin necesidad de contraseña y como se ejecuta a traves de `root` no te debería de dar problemas.